# Окончания существительных второго склонения в именительном падеже множественного числа

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте!
У меня с коллегой по работе возник спор по поводу окончаний существительных второго склонения в именительном падеже множественного числа.
Все началось со слова "договОр" (мн. ~ы/~а). Сошлись на том, что правильно говорить договОры, однако не можем прийти к единому мнению насчет слов *мастер*, *паспорт*, *дом*. Какие окончания будут у этих слов в именительном падеже множественного числа? Существует ли какое-то правило окончаний в данном случае? Почему у слов одного склонения встречаются разные окончания?

Answer (score 1):

А единого окончания и нет. Собственно, окончание "-а" в подобных словах появилось в языке недавно (например, в 19 веке говорили "учители", "домы" и т.д.). Окончание "-а" присутствовало только в профжаргонах (например, "шофера"), но в литературной речи их не было. Но постепенно это окончание стало проникать и в обычную речь, отсюда и разночтения.
Так, "договорЫ", "кремЫ", "кабелИ", но "домА", "паспортА".

Comment: Помню, как меня лет 35 назад раздражала надпись на хлебном магазине "Торта, кекса". Да еще так солидно выполненная!

Comment: Интересно было бы узнать, почему языку "понадобилось" новое окончание? Кстати, оно приводит и к сдвигу ударения: пАспорты -> паспортА.

Comment: Иногда окончание играет смыслоразличительную роль. например, в школе учителЯ, а идейные наставники - учИтели.